# AdMob "currency" system

Tags: android, admob

I have an app which uses a virtual currency to do certain actions. You get "coins" each time you click on an ad.

Is this against AdMob TOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quote from the [*Terms Of Use*](http://www.admob.com/home/terms) under the title *RESTRICTIONS*

> User shall not, and shall not authorize or encourage any third party
>   to generate fraudulent impressions of or fraudulent clicks on any
>   advertisement, including but not limited to, through repeated manual
>   clicks, the use of robots or other automated query tools and/or
>   computer generated search requests, and/or the fraudulent use of other
>   search engine optimization services and/or software.

And this one is from the [Integration / implementation dos and don'ts](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2790280&topic=2790017&ctx=topic) Google Support website

> Users should not be encouraged to click on ads
>
> Phrases such as “click the ads” or similar language are not allowed.
>   Any compensation or other incentives to click ads are strictly
>   prohibited. Additionally, incentivizing users to click on links and/or
>   non-AdMob ads is also prohibited, as it will train users to perform
>   actions that cause invalid activity.

It clearly states that *it is not allowed*. I would normally stay away from such an activity if I want to continue using the Admobs platform.

Comment: Is there any other ad platform that allows this while giving decent revenue?

Comment: I have heard [MobFox](http://www.mobfox.com) pays better revenue. But I am personally with AdMob and haven't thought of switching yet.